# Outer product matrix multiplication

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication

Trying to find the outer product of two matrices `A` and `B`

Here is what I have attempted:

```
function product(A, B)
    n_a, m_a = size(A)
    n_b, m_b = size(B)
    AB = Array{Float64}(undef, n_a, m_b)
    for i in 1:n_a
        for j in 1:m_b
            AB[i, j] = A[:, j] * B[j, :]'
        end
    end
    return AB
end

product(A, B)
```

I get an error when attempting to run: `` Cannot `convert` an object of type Matrix{Float64} to an object of type Float64 ``

Comment: what type are `A` and `B`?

Comment: A and B are Float64 arrays @OscarSmith

Comment: `Vector` or `Matrix`? (both are `Array`s)

Comment: @OscarSmith i did typeof(A) and also for B and C and it resulted in `Matrix{Float64}` for all of them. dimensions also should work for matrix multiplicationn (n,p) * (p,m) -> (n,m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked image and the text, I think the formula tries to show another representation for the usual matrix product, which is useful, especially when doing rank decomposition of matrices (as sums of rank one matrices).
As a concrete example, first defining a couple of matrices:

```
julia> using Random
julia> Random.seed!(1234);

julia> A = rand(1:10,(2,3))
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  3  4
 6  9  4

julia> B = rand(1:10,(3,4))
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 10  8  1   7
  8  6  2  10
  5  8  5   7
```

Now define a product as a sum of outer products of vectors, and see it gives the same result as a usual matrix product:

```
julia> product(A, B) = sum( [ A[:,i] * B[i,:]' for i=1:size(A,2) ] )
product (generic function with 1 method)

julia> product(A,B)
2×4 Matrix{Int64}:
  84   82  30   86
 152  134  44  160

julia> A*B
2×4 Matrix{Int64}:
  84   82  30   86
 152  134  44  160
```

In this example, the resulting matrix can be at most rank 3, the number of columns in A (and rows in B). In fact, it is rank 2 because of number of rows, but in general this product is done on tall times flat matrices and then the rank restriction is meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "outer product of matrices", I'm only familiar with an outer product of vectors (which creates a matrix). Could you clarify what output you're looking for with an example?

In any event to address the immediate issue: The stacktrace is pointing to this line in your function:

```
AB[i, j] = A[:, j] * B[j, :]'
```

Let's take two example matrices and see what happens for `i=j=1`:

```
julia> x = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> y = [2 3; 4 5]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  3
 4  5

julia> x[:, 1] * y[1, :]'
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 2  3
 6  9
```

so the way you are slicing and transposing your matrices means you are calculating an outer product (as I know it) of two vectors, which gives you a matrix. Given that `AB` is defined as a matrix of Float64s, the location `AB[i, j]` can only hold a Float64 value, but you are trying to assign a `Matrix{Float64}` to it.

Again I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here, but if it's just a "normal" matrix multiplication, you should have

```
AB[i, j] = A[i, :]' * B[:, j]
```

in your inner loop. Making that change gives me:

```
julia> product(x, y) == x * y
true
```

for the `x` and `y` defined above.

Comment: thank you for your response, what you have done there is the inner product from what I understand. I now see the problem with what I had done, see [image](https://ibb.co/PZ2VtcZ) for the equation that represents what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the image you linked to in the comment, you're calculating an array of matrices. This can be done as follows:

```
AB = [A[:,j]*B[j,:]' for j=1:size(A,2)]
```

Though, I don't believe that's the correct definition for matrix outer product. I think it should be like this:

```
AB = [r*c' for r in eachrow(A), c in eachcol(B)]
```

This will give you a `[n_a*m_b]` matrix of `[m_a*n_b]` matrices.